# Pandas how add a new column to dataframe based on values from all rows, specific columns values applied to whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I working on a pandas DataFrame which needs a new column that shows count of specific values in specific columns.

I tried various combinations groupby and pivot, but had problems to apply it to whole dataframe without errors.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', 'z'],
    ['a', 'x'],
    ['a', 'y'],
    ['b', 'v'],
    ['b', 'x'],
    ['b', 'v']],
  columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

I need to add col3 that counts 'v' values in col2 for each value in 'col1'. There is no 'v' in col2 for 'a' in col1, so it's 0 everywhere, while expected value count is 2 for 'b', also in a row where value in col2 equals 'x' instead of 'v'.

Expected output:

```
['a', 'z', 0]
['a', 'x', 0]
['a', 'y', 0]
['b', 'v', 2]
['b', 'x', 2]
['b', 'v', 2]
```

I'm looking rather for a nice pandas specific solution because the original dataframe is quite big, so things like row iterations and time expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While ALollz's answer is neat and a one liner, here is another one although a two step solution introducing you to other concepts like `str.contains` and `np.where`!

First get the rows which have `v` using `np.where` and mark them as a flag:

```
df['col3'] = np.where(df['col2'].str.contains('v'), 1, 0)
```

Now perform a `groupby` on `col1` and `sum` them:

```
df['col3'] = df.groupby('col1')['col3'].transform('sum')
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2  col3
0    a    z     0
1    a    x     0
2    a    y     0
3    b    v     2
4    b    x     2
5    b    v     2
```

Comment: I like this one because arguments can be freely extended for both ```where``` and ```groupby``` for more sophisticated calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Boolean Series checking the equality then `groupby` +`transform` + `sum` to count them.

```
df['col3'] = df.col2.eq('v').astype(int).groupby(df.col1).transform('sum')  

#  col1 col2  col3
#0    a    z     0
#1    a    x     0
#2    a    y     0
#3    b    v     2
#4    b    x     2
#5    b    v     2
```

Comment: Super neat stuff :)

Comment: Works nicely and can be easily developed, i.e. extend the ```groupby``` arguments by more columns on more complex dataframes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above are fine. The only caveat is that `transform` can be slow when the group size is very large. Alternatively, you can try the workaround below,

```
(df.assign(mask = lambda x:x.col2.eq('v'))
   .pipe(lambda x:x.join(x.groupby('col1')['mask'].sum().map(int).rename('col3'),on='col1')))
```

Comment: It doesn't work and prompts this: ```ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['col3'], dtype='object')```. Could you please advise?